# The ability to sort 'questions/unanswered' by 'week' & 'month' just like 'questions/no-answers' can

Tags: feature-request, feed, api

I want to setup a Stack2RSS feed to `questions/unanswered` but I only want to see posts that are no more than a week old.  It appears that [questions/no-answers](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-with-no-answers) can do this via the 'sort' parameter set to 'week' or 'month' but no such sorting exists for 'unanswered'.

The only work around I found so far is through the use of the 'fromdate' parameter but this isn't very maintainable as it takes an absolute epoch time rather than a relative time.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is a limitation of the API. You might want to request this as a feature over on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).